# Debian password change discarded

Tags: debian, password

I use [Volumio](https://volumio.org/technical-overview/), built on Debian. I want to change the password for the default `volumio` user, so I type:

```
volumio@volumio:~$ sudo passwd
[sudo] password for volumio:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
volumio@volumio:~$ reboot
```

When the device restarts, the new password doesn't work but the old one does.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resetting root's password when using `sudo passwd`. The command literally means 'run passwd as root'.

To change the user's password, you simply use `passwd`. This command is meant to be used by standard users. This works because the command file is assigned the 'suid' bit.